# How to get all rows inside table that have same class selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get rows from a table that is generated dynamically with many other tables that have the same classes selector.

I tried to use a class selector $('.test') but it's render all tr in all tables with the selector $('.test')

Comment: so select the table, and then the rows....

Comment: you should post your HTML to question

Comment: Are you attempting to get ONLY the rows with class "test" that were dynamically generated? Or only the rows from one specific table with class "test" ?

Comment: Remember to share your code. You cant ask a plain text question. Show your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Add something unique to the table (a unique class, an id…) and use it in your selector.

```
$("#the-table .test");
```

If you can't add this since it's generated but if your tables are siblings, you can use a :nth-child() selector.

```
$("table:nth-child(3) .test");
```

Answer (score 0):

First put a data-table to the table and the data-row to the rows, something like:

```js
$('[data-trigger]').click(function(){
$('[data-table]').find('[data-row]').toggleClass('change');
});
```

```css
tr.change td{
background-color:coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-row>
      <td>Hi</td>
    </tr>
     <tr data-row>
      <td>Bye</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" data-trigger>Change color of rows</button>
```